# Force MS Access ODBC Connection to use SQL Server Authentication

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, vba, odbc

I'm using the following code that is run from my Autoexec macro to make the ODBC connection.

```
'Name     :   CreateDSNConnection
'Purpose  :   Create a DSN to link tables to SQL Server
'Parameters
'     sServer: Name of SQL Server that you are linking to
'     sDatabase: Name of the SQL Server database that you are linking to
'     sUsername: Name of the SQL Server user who can connect to SQL Server, leave blank to use a Trusted Connection
'     sPassword: SQL Server user password
Public Function CreateDSNConnection(sServer As String, sDatabase As String, sUsername As String, sPassword As String) As Boolean
Dim sConnect As String
On Error GoTo CreateDSNConnection_Err

  If Len(sUsername) = 0 Then
    '//Use trusted authentication if stUsername is not supplied.
    sConnect = "Description=DBTraining" & vbCr & "SERVER=" & sServer & vbCr & "DATABASE=" & sDatabase & vbCr & "Trusted_Connection=Yes"
  Else
    sConnect = "Description=DBTraining" & vbCr & "SERVER=" & sServer & vbCr & "DATABASE=" & sDatabase
  End If

  DBEngine.RegisterDatabase "DBTraining", "SQL Server", True, sConnect

  'Add error checking.
  CreateDSNConnection = True
  Debug.Print "Connection made"
  Exit Function

CreateDSNConnection_Err:
  CreateDSNConnection = False
  MsgBox "CreateDSNConnection encountered an unexpected error: " & Err.Description, vbCritical, "Unexpected Error!"

End Function
```

Pretty standard stuff...but it seems that the ODBC connection is always setup as using Windows auth and I need it setup to use SQL Server auth.  I've tried dropping in the `UID=` and `PWD=`, but it still tries to use Windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What ended up working for me was starting it over from scratch.

- I blew out the existing UserDSN from the ODBC connection.
- Then opened my DB and ran the CreateDSNConnection code
- That put the UserDSN back in, and was set to use SQL Server Authentication, but was using my Windows login
- Deleted all linked tables and views
- Recreated the links for tables and views using the Generic SQL login account and checked the Save password option
- Compacted & Repaired
- Sent to a user to test...it worked

I had tried every one of these steps multiple times...except for the first one.  I'm guessing that there was something corrupted in the UserDSN file???  I have no idea.  But deleting it and starting over completely resolved the issue.

Comment: What occurs is any table you open, then Access will cache the information. From that point on EVEN a re-link will re-use that cached information. The VERY important concept is thus to ensure that when you launch Access that no table EVER opened or used BEFORE you re-link. So no startup forms etc. can be allowed. In fact this effect can be put to good use since you do NOT need to include UID/PASSWORD in the SQL link string. How this works is explained here: http://blogs.office.com/b/microsoft-access/archive/2011/04/08/power-tip-improve-the-security-of-database-connections.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Here is a trusted connection from Access to SQL Server:

```
strConnectString = "Driver={SQL Server};" & _
                   "Server=" & strDSN & ";" & _
                   "Database=" & strDatabase & ";" & _
                    "Trusted_Connection=yes"
```

Or for SQL Server Authentication:

```
strConnectString = "Driver={SQL Server};" & _
                   "Server=" & strDSN & ";" & _
                   "Database=" & strDatabase & ";" & _
                   "User Id=,myUID>;Password=<MyPWD>"
```

Comment: @Rdster: you can also try adding an explicit `;Trusted_Connection=No`

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim CurConn As ADODB.Connection
Set CurConn = New ADODB.Connection
CurConn.Open "Provider=myProvider;" & _
             "Server=myServer;" & _
             "Database=myDatabase;" & _
             "Trusted_Connection=no;" & _
             "User Id=myUsername;" & _
             "Password=myPassword;"
```

This, how I do it in Access VBA.